# How to programmatically compose ndb.AND to query a repeated property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I've got a Google App engine NDB's entity with a repeated KeyProperty I want to query for with an "including AND" on a list of elements.

I'm referring to the "solution 2" listed here: [How to query with a list object on repeated string property in ndb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937355/how-to-query-with-a-list-object-on-repeated-string-property-in-ndb), the problem is that I don't know how many elements has the query list.

This is my model:

```
class Record(ndb.Expando):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    ref = ndb.KeyProperty(Client, repeated=True)
```

and those my query attempts:

```
q = Record.query()
for client in getlist('ref[]'):
            q.filter(Record.ref == ndb.Key(urlsafe=client))
```

or

```
q.filter(Record.ref == [ndb.Key(urlsafe=elem) for elem in getlist('ref[]')])
```

I think the best way to achieve the inclusive and query on a repeated property is with `ndb.AND` operator, as in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or and in the above mentioned SO response, but I need to "compose" it with an unknown number of elements... `ndb.AND(kind.prop==elem_1, kind.prop==elem_2, ...kind.prop==elem_N)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure if the `ndb.AND` would accept a string programmatically generated that you could use to filter.

Therefore another approach that you could follow is using the `IN` filter. In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#repeated_properties) there's information on how to filter repeated properties and an example in the usage of `IN`.

The process I would follow will be:

```
# generate properties to filter
#property array will look like:
#[poperty1, property2, property3, ....., propertyN]
properties = [property for property in properties]

# filter using the previous generated properties
q = Records.query(Records.ref.IN(properties))

# then manually filter the results
for result in q:
# apply custom filters
    if result.ref == 'property1' and result.ref == 'property2':
        #dosomething
```

This way you can achieve a similar functionality as you will first have all entities containing at least one property from the `IN` filter and then you can manually process them and implement the AND filter.

Comment: What if - as stated in the question - I don't know how many are the elements in properties array?

Comment: I guess that by saying that you don't know how many elements you mean that you are creating them in your code? Properties array can be created programmatically , hence the code will create N properties even if you don't know the exact value for N. I am editing the answer to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

According to some more deep googling, maybe my approach to one-to-many in NDB it's wrong.

Now I'm trying to keep the reference property in the referenced entity.... as in:

```
class Client(ndb.Model):
  prop = ndb.StringProperty()
  ref = ndb.KeyProperty(Record, repeated=True)

class Record(ndb.Model):
  prop = ndb.StringProperty()
```